# doctrine 2 querybuilder like inside having

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

When using QueryBuilder object with `like` inside `having` as below:

```
$queuebuilder->addSelect('c.customercount*5 as count');
$queuebuilder->add('having', 'count like \'sometext\'');
```

I get an error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 741: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got count

This happpens only with aliased coloumn. How to avoid the error?
thank you.

Comment: Well, you need at at first place, learn how to write a question correctly, because you did not format your code, and you code looks like incomplete. Can you please provide the code as you have it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$qb->select('count(c.customer) as count');
$qb->having('count > x');
```

If you want to include where statements you could do something like this:

```
$qb->select('count(c.customer) as count');
$qb->where('c.username = :username');
$qb->having('count > ?1');
$qb->setParameter('username', "foo");
$qb->setParameter(1, 3); //havin count > 3
```

Comment: thank you
I use datatables.js plugin and I need to have code like this:[code]$qb->select('count(c.customer) as count');
[code]$qb->having('count like \'%param%\'');
but like keyword does not work

Comment: I don't know how else should I explain my question to let you know that I need NOT HIGHER AND NOT LESS, BUT SEARCH USING LIKE KEYWORD.
[like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: Come on dude,  don't get angry.  What happening here is that you  query has no sense.  If you only want use LIKE condition you could do:   - >where("column like :param")